# Cluster stops writing operation while a member joins Hazelcast cluster

Tags: java, hazelcast

There seems to be a writing problem when a member joins a Hazelcast cluster.

When a member joins, will it immediately trigger a partition transmission?

Will the partition transmission block the map put operation?

Comment: Fixed grammar and wording.

It is always good to start the question with a detailed problem. All we know is there is a writing problem when someone joins. How did you discover the problem, what else have you looked at as possible problems besides the member joining? Have you encountered any error messages which might help.

The more information you give the easier it is for someone knowledgeable to pick up on your question and provide you with answers.

Answer (score 0):

When a member joins the cluster, repartitioning starts immediately. Put operations are blocked and queued only for those partitions that are in transit - migrating from old node to the new. As soon as  partitions migrate successfully, the queued put operations are then automatically sent to the new partition owners.